# Why using `fakeAsync` test does not make test code run in async way?

Tags: angular

According to angular docs https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#async-test-with-fakeasync

using `Observable` `fakeAsync` and `tick()` should allow to test async entities.
I have create test, that in my opinion is a counterpart of code presented in docs (without component). Unfortunetely it fails. Can you please explain why?

```
  it('how to test observables. Example #5', fakeAsync(() => {
    let progress = true;
    // of(['somevalemiitter']) //without asapScheduler, it will fail
    throwError('bleblebl') //without asapScheduler, it will fail
      .pipe(finalize(() => {
        progress = false;
        // done();
      }))
      .subscribe(console.log, err => console.log(err));
    expect(progress).toBeTruthy();
    console.log('before tick');
    tick();
    console.log('after tick');
    expect(progress).toBeFalsy();
  }));
```

outputs;

```
'bleblebl'
'before tick'
'after tick'
```

Where I would expect it to be

```
'before tick'
'bleblebl'
'after tick'
```

only because of using `fakeAsync`. If I use `asapScheduler` then it works as expected.

Comment: throwError and of functions are synchronous, so in your example everything is correct. If you want to mock asynchronous behaviour please use asyncScheduler.

Comment: but why using `tick` in the first place if everything is already resolved....

Comment: `tick` simulates passing time, but if you don't have async actions (micro and macrotasks) `tick` does nothing to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just seems to be the specified behavior of `throwError`, the subscription is handled synchronously - so there is nothing wrong with your test or `fakeAsync`.

E.g. this method in an Angular component:

```
handleClick() {
  throwError("test").subscribe(console.log, console.log);
  console.log("test2");
}
```

This results in:

```
test  
test2
```

Comment: What is the point of `tick` in the code then (its taken from docs)

Comment: If you have an async action (e.g. an interval or an api call), tick will simulate time passing in the scheduler so you can check post conditions after the async action is done. tick can also be used with a number, meaning that it will simulate the passing of given ms, e.g. tick(1000).

Comment: So using that in the example from docs i missleading simply missleading (at least to me)

Comment: In the example the component has a setTimeout (which behaves async):  `setTimeout(() => this.errorMessage = err.message || err.toString());` Therefore they use tick to make sure the timeout was evaulated.

Comment: ahh I actually skipped that part,

Comment: Np. I would appreciate if you could upvote and accept the answer if it helped you. cheers.